Sparse Hamiltonian with internal DOFs band separation
I've created in matlab a sparse matrix hamiltonian of 2D cubic lattice, nothing special.
I have another atom in the unit cell and both have 2 spins DOFs,
so I should get 4 bands dependent on particle number.
the problem is my matrix is of size 4*N^2, and I don't know how to separate the different bands and their eigenvectors.
I tried separating in gups of 4 but the diagonalization hasn't arranged them in any particular way it seems.
I'm not sure what to think of this

Maybe you could look in momentum space? (Fourier transforming those eigenvectors you found wouldn't be much extra work compared to the actual calculation to find them.)

In principle, you should find the list of eigenvalues $\varepsilon_n$ (where $n=1,\dots,4N$) and relative eigenvectors $\vec{v}_n$, and you should:

sort the list of eigenvalues from smallest to largest
sort the list of eigenvectors by the corresponding eigenvalue.

If you plot a histogram of the eigenvalues, you should be able to see the density of states and, in case the band structure is gapped, you should be able to recognize the different bands.
Obviously with this approach you cannot see the dispersion of your band with respect to the crystal momentum $\vec{k}$. If you want this, you should first rewrite your Hamiltonian with a Fourier transformation to momentum space, then you should get a $4\times 4$ Hamiltonian with entries dependent on $\vec{k}$. At this point you can sample the momentum space with a suitable grid and you can compute 4 eigenvalues for every sampled value of $\vec{k}$. If you want I can elaborate more on this.
